# How to add a link to the users sandbox as on Wikipedia?

Tags: mediawiki

The page MediaWiki:Sidebar allows you to change/add to the menu on the left. So how to add or change items in the menu at the top, (is there a MediaWiki:Topbar page)? Specifically, how to add a link to the users sandbox as on Wikipedia?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This adds a "Sandbox" link to the personal toolbar area, like on Wikipedia.

It does need an extension - if not installed already, install the [Gadgets extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aGadgets).

Add the page [MediaWiki:Gadget-mySandbox.js](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MediaWiki%3aGadget-mySandbox.js).

Edit the pages MediaWiki:Gadgets-definition‎ with

> mySandbox[ResourceLoader|dependencies=mediawiki.util,mediawiki.Title,mediawiki.Uri|default|rights=createpage]|mySandbox.js

and MediaWiki:Gadget-mySandbox with eg.

> Add a "Sandbox" link to the personal toolbar area.

It will be then enabled by default in Special:Preferences#mw-prefsection-gadgets